# Implement queue based on linked list in C++: Error: free() invalid pointer: 0x000...400c1c * (Core dumped)

Tags: c++, queue, destructor

I am learning the algorithms  in < Algorithms> in C++, and now I want to implement the Queue based on linked list. Following is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template <typename T>
class Node
{
    public:
        typedef T data_t;
        typedef Node<T>* NodePtr;
        data_t item;
        NodePtr next;
};
// Queue: FIFO
 template <typename T>
class Queue
{
    public:
        typedef T data_t;
        Queue();

        bool isEmpty()
        {
            return first == nullptr;
        }
        size_t size()
       {
           return N;
       }

       void enqueue(data_t d)
       {
            //temp = new Node<data_t>();
            temp = last;
            last = new Node<data_t>();
            last->item = d;
            last->next = nullptr;
            if(isEmpty())
                first = last;
            else
                temp->next = last;

            N++;
        }

        data_t dequeue()
        {
            data_t t = first->item;
            temp = first;
            first = first->next;
            temp->next = nullptr;
            delete temp;
            temp = nullptr;
            N--;
            if(isEmpty())
                last = nullptr;

            return t;
        }
        ~Queue();
    private:
        int N = 0;
        typename Node<data_t>::NodePtr first = nullptr;
        typename Node<data_t>::NodePtr last = nullptr;
        typename Node<data_t>::NodePtr temp = nullptr;
};

 template <typename T>
 Queue<T>::Queue()
{
    N = 0; 
    first = nullptr;
    last = nullptr;
    temp = nullptr;
}
template <typename T>
Queue<T>::~Queue()
{
    cout << "In destructure function ..." << endl;
    while(!isEmpty())
    {
        temp = first->next;
        delete first;
        first = temp;
        N--;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Queue<int> que;
    que.enqueue(1);
    que.enqueue(2);
    cout << "queue's size = " << que.size() << endl;
    cout << que.dequeue() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

It's alright before the "return 0;" in main function, and this error happens when existing main function.

I guess some mistakes exist in my destructor funciton of class Queue.

What's more, I tried to writing "~Node()" in 'class Node' and didn't use the destructor function in 'class Queue', but not work both.

I've searched this error for one day and not find exactly same problem. Thankyou very much ~

Comment: `temp` should be a local variable wherever it is used, nt a member variable, and the whole thing is not threadsafe. There is plenty of working code for this available. Check it.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Actually, I've used same code structure to implement 'Stack' based on 'linked list' and can run without errors. But I'll try it again with your suggestion...

Comment: [It works as expected for me](https://ideone.com/76ouOD), perhaps there's something off with they way you compile it?

Comment: I used g++ -std=c++11 under ubuntu 14.04 to compile the code. I guess that the 'ideone' website using gcc 6.3 may help to eleminate some implicit errors in code .
Anyway, thanks for your help